# API search engines - the list of search engines

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, search-engine, firefox-addon-sdk

How to get an array of search engines added to Firefox?
There is such a thing, but I do not know if it's just because e know how to use it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Mozmill_tests/Shared_Modules/SearchAPI/engineManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`nsIBrowserSearchService`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/public/nsIBrowserSearchService.idl) to enumerate `nsISearchEngine` instances, aka. the search engines.

```
var bss = Cc["@mozilla.org/browser/search-service;1"].
          getService(Ci.nsIBrowserSearchService);
bss.init(function() {
  for (var e of bss.getEngines() /* nsISearchEngine */) {
    console.log(e.name, e.description);
  }
  console.log("default:", bss.defaultEngine.name);
  console.log("current:", bss.currentEngine.name);
});
```

If you're using the SDK, you may need to

```
let {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
```

`browser.xul` overlays in XUL add-ons should be fine, otherwise a common pattern in XUL add-ons is something like:

```
let {classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci} = Components;
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: Cc is not defined`
What to do?

Comment: *Edit 1* added regarding `Cc`/`Ci`

Comment: I like this. We got 3 different answers on this same question its real nice to see this variety. :) https://ask.mozilla.org/question/758/api-search-engines-the-list-of-search-engines/

Comment: The answers are actually doing the same thing, more or less. `Services.search` happens to be `nsIBrowserSearchService`, so those bits are equal. The **sample** I gave uses `getEngines()` instead of `getVisibleEngines()` and uses `for of` instead of `forEach` and displays a different set of information based on that... Anyways, both things are samples, the important bits to the answers are the pointers to the `nsIBrowserSearchService` and `nsISearchEngine` interfaces.